# is it safe to return primary keys on ajax returns for jquery datatable or other ajax return?

Tags: ajax, datatable

We've been using using ajax request to fill our jquery datatable. Problem is when we do it this way you can see the ajax return on the browser dev tools.

is this alright?

should we not return the primary key and instead return another unique identifier?

if not what is the best way to do it?

you can just use a basic Users Table for explanation/examples